# How to scan a document with the scanner scan button

Tags: canon, scanning

I have a Canon MP250 printer/scanner and I wonder if I can use the [Scan] button of this device to automatically scan a document, page by page.

This device has its own software to do this, but it is only to Windows (doesn't run with Lubuntu, even under Wine).

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this does not work in Linux. The only solution is to create a Windows virtual machine and install the software there. This will also let you access advanced scanning features that the simplified `scangearmp2` program does not.

Comment: I see. Well, it's a pity this function doesn't work on Linux. I hope somebody performs some upgrade to this. Thanks a lot for your hepl!!!

Comment: I hope so too!!

Answer (score 0):

If your scanner works with Sane, [it should work with the ScanBD project.](http://thehomeserverhandbook.com/2012/03/03/scanbd_part1/)  Unfortunately it's not always plug-and-play, you'll probably have to do a fair bit of manual scripting.

I haven't researched your specific scanner, I'm afraid.

Comment: I downloaded the compressed file of ScanBD, but it contains a lot of folders and files!!! What do I have to do with all those elements?

Comment: As the other poster said, this doesn't work by default in Linux.  That's not the same as "it's not possible in Linux", though.  It's possible.  But it will require you to learn a lot about the guts of your system.  The link I posted has the steps required.  But you'll have to follow the steps and make a strong effort to understand what's happening at every step.  Nobody is going to be able to simply tell you how to get it running.